# Why does std::experimental::filesystem::path not accept wildcards like "*"?

Tags: c++, filesystems, standards, c++17

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::path p("/usr/include/c++/../sys/*");
    p = fs::canonical(p);
}
```

gcc 6.2.0 compiles ok, but the runtime error says:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
>   what():  filesystem error: cannot canonicalize: No such file or
>   directory [/usr/include/c++/../sys/*] [/data/svn/yaoxinliu] Aborted

**Why does** `std::experimental::filesystem::path` **not accept wildcards like** `*`**?**

Comment: It's fundamental to the design that a path corresponds to a single file, not an arbitrary set of files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/canonical)

> `std::experimental::filesystem::canonical` converts path p to a canonical absolute path, i.e. an absolute path that has no dot, dot-dot elements or **symbolic links**.

Since `std::experimental::filesystem::canonical` must also dereference the symbolic links contained in the path it can only accept paths of existing files or directories.